# How Can I Write Logs Directly to AWS S3 from Memory Without First Writing to stdout? (Python, boto3)

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm trying to write Python log files directly to S3 without first saving them to stdout. I want the log files to be written to S3 automatically when the program is done running. I'd like to use the boto3 `put_object` method:

```
import atexit
import logging

import boto3  


def write_logs(body, bucket, key):
    s3 = boto3.client("s3")
    s3.put_object(Body=body, Bucket=bucket, Key=key)

log = logging.getLogger("some_log_name")
log.info("Hello S3")

atexit.register(write_logs, body=log, bucket="bucket_name", key="key_name")

quit()
```

This throws an error when uploading to S3. If i remember correctly, it requires that the object uploaded to S3 must be bytes-like. I'll update the question with the exact error once I have time to recreate the issue.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to add a couple things here. First, create a StringIO object. Then, write the logs to the StringIO object using a logging StreamHandler. Add the handler to your logger. Finally, call the `getvalue()` method on the StringIO object. You can write that to S3.

```
import atexit
import io
import logging

import boto3  


def write_logs(body, bucket, key):
    s3 = boto3.client("s3")
    s3.put_object(Body=body, Bucket=bucket, Key=key)  


log = logging.getLogger("some_log_name")
log_stringio = io.StringIO()
handler = logging.StreamHandler(log_stringio)
log.addHandler(handler)

atexit.register(write_logs, body=log_stringio.getvalue(), bucket="bucket_name", key="key_name")

log.info("Hello S3")

quit()
```

Comment: `atexit` ... TIL

Comment: btw it's `log.addHandler(handler)` (without `self.`)

Comment: @shadi good catch. I extracted it out of its class for simplicity for Stack Overflow. Thanks :)

Comment: If you didn't see any output from above code, as the [doco](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#a-simple-example) indicated, by default logging level is set to warning. So log.info("Hello S3") will not output anything, unless change the logging level to info by `logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)`

Comment: It wasn't working for me when I register `log_stringio.getvalue()` to `atexit`. So I just registered `log_stringio` and in the `write_log` function called the `get_value()` ->  `s3.put_object(Body=body.getvalue(), Bucket=bucket, Key=key)`

Comment: ```s3.put_object(Body=body, Bucket=bucket, Key=key) ```
don't will overwrite the bucket every call?

Comment: @ShooLimberger `Bucket` is a required parameter for `put_object`. It's just the name of the bucket where you're writing an object. See the [documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_object)

Comment: can anybody help for this .Not working for me


s3 = boto3.client("s3")

def write_logs(body, bucket, key): 
    s3.put_object(Body=body.getvalue(), Bucket=bucket, Key=key)  

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
log = logging.getLogger()

log_stringio = io.StringIO()
handler = logging.StreamHandler(log_stringio)
log.addHandler(handler)
    


def lambda_handler(event, context):

    
    print(log_stringio.getvalue())
    atexit.register(write_logs, body=log_stringio, bucket="6dlogs1", key="testlogs/123.log")
    log.warn("Hello S3")

Comment: @RNHTTR: Super helpful, but there's a bug in this answer: `body=log_stringio.getvalue()` is evaluated when you call `atexit.register`, and since you haven't logged anything at that point, `body` is blank. To fix it, you can either pass `log_stringio` into the `write_logs` function and call `getvalue()` on it there, or pass the function itself.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work (anymore?). I get a `RuntimeError: can't register atexit after shutdown`.

Comment: Ok. This is currently broken on Python 3.9.9 with boto 1.21.42. See https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/3221