# How to log directly to s3 in python

Tags: python, amazon-s3, logging

Using the logging library is it possible to directly log to s3? And not write to stdout. (I also have other print statements in the program taht should print to stdout)
Currently my code is like this:

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
log = logging.getLogger("MyLog")
log_stringio = io.StringIO()
handler = logging.StreamHandler(log_stringio)
log.addHandler(handler)

def write_logs(body, bucket, key):
    body = body.getvalue()
    s3 = boto3.client("s3")
    s3.put_object(Body=body, Bucket=bucket, Key=key)   

atexit.register(write_logs, body=log_stringio, bucket="abc", key="def")
```

This code while writes to log, it also writes to stdout. Any idea how to prevent this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How Can I Write Logs Directly to AWS S3 from Memory Without First Writing to stdout? (Python, boto3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51070891/how-can-i-write-logs-directly-to-aws-s3-from-memory-without-first-writing-to-std)

Comment: I did look at this, but it still prints to stdout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amazon S3 objects are **immutable**. It is not possible to 'append' to an object.

The `s3.put_object()` command is creating the object and its contents. Any subsequent call to `put_object()` will *replace* the contents of the object (effectively, it makes a *new* object with the same name).