# Using Python Logging module to save logs to S3, how to capture all levels of logs for all modules?

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, logging

It's my first time using the logging module in Python(3.7). My code uses imported modules that also have their own log statements. When I first added log statements to my code, I didn't use getLogger(). I just used `logging.basicConfig(filename)` and called `logger.debug()` directly to log statements. When I did this, all the logs from both my script and also all the imported modules was output to the same file together.

Now I need to convert my code to save logs to s3 instead of a file. I tried the solution mentioned in [How Can I Write Logs Directly to AWS S3 from Memory Without First Writing to stdout? (Python, boto3) - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51070891/how-can-i-write-logs-directly-to-aws-s3-from-memory-without-first-writing-to-std) but I have two issues with it:

1. None of the 'prefixes' are present in the output when I check on s3.
2. Only INFO statements are showing up. I was under the impression that `logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)` would make it would output all logs at or *above* level INFO, but I'm only seeing INFO. Also, only INFO logs get printed to stdout, when before all levels were. I don't know why the 'prefixes' are missing.

```py
from psaw import PushshiftAPI
api = PushshiftAPI()
import time
import logging
import boto3
import io
import atexit

def write_logs(body, bucket, key):
    s3 = boto3.client("s3")
    s3.put_object(Body=body.getvalue(), Bucket=bucket, Key=key)

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
log = logging.getLogger()
log_stringio = io.StringIO()
handler = logging.StreamHandler(log_stringio)
log.addHandler(handler)

def collectRange(sub,start,end):
    atexit.register(write_logs, body=log_stringio, bucket="<...>", key=f'{sub}/log.txt')
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    object = s3.Object('<...>', f'{sub}/{sub}@{start}-{end}.csv')
    now = time.time()
    logging.info(f'Start Time:{now}')
    logging.debug('First request')
    gen = api.search_comments(after=start, before=end,<...>, subreddit=sub)
    r=next(gen)
    <...>
    quit()
```

Output:

```
Found credentials in shared credentials file: ~/.aws/credentials
Start Time:1591310443.7060978
https://api.pushshift.io/reddit/comment/search?<...>
https://api.pushshift.io/reddit/comment/search?<...>
```

Desired output:

```
INFO:botocore.credentials:Found credentials in shared credentials file: ~/.aws/credentials
INFO:root:Start Time:1591310443.7060978
DEBUG:root:First request
INFO:psaw.PushshiftAPI:https://api.pushshift.io/reddit/comment/search?<...>
DEBUG:psaw.PushshiftAPI:<whatever is usually here>
DEBUG:psaw.PushshiftAPI:<whatever is usually here>
INFO:psaw.PushshiftAPI:https://api.pushshift.io/reddit/comment/search?<...>
DEBUG:psaw.PushshiftAPI:<whatever is usually here>
DEBUG:psaw.PushshiftAPI:<whatever is usually here>
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: running into similar situation where logs from other imported models are not captured and the timestamps with log level is missing. Were you able to find a solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can at least add the level name (or time) by following this documentation:
[Changing the format of displayed messages](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#changing-the-format-of-displayed-messages).

And to get DEBUG as well you need to use the following instead of INFO

```py
logging.basicConfig(..., level=logging.DEBUG)
```