# How to write logger info to s3 bucket from AWS GLUE job

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue

I have a small script, which will save the logger info in the local file system

but I'm planning to run this file in AWS Glue, and want to save the log in the s3 bucket, I gave the path, the program is running successfully but the file is not saving in S3

```
import logging, pandas as pd
import boto3


s3 = boto3.client('s3')


#logging configuration
#logging levels are INFO,Debug,Error,WARN,FATAL



logging.basicConfig(filename='<bucketname>/spark.logs',level=logging.INFO)

#spark = createSparkDriver()
logging.info('Spark driver created sucessfully {}'.format('SUCCESS'))

logging.info('source_df printSchema')

print('DoneSUCCESS')
```

Can you anyone help me

Comment: There is a similar discussion on the question asked here:> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51070891/how-can-i-write-logs-directly-to-aws-s3-from-memory-without-first-writing-to-std

Comment: Thank you  @Eman, but it's not working when i running this script in Glue Python Shell
Throwing this error
'SystemExit: None'

Comment: A python shell environment works differently to a spark job. The system exit error that you are seeing, please check the CloudWatch logs for details. It could be possible that one of the modules you are using is not being installed properly.

Comment: from the link i code, no other libraries used, just want to load error log, in cloud watch, it  only showing print message SUCCESS in error dir, and in glue job history I can see 'SystemExit: None'